# How can I return my view along with my model and keep some url parameters using mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, navigation

I know that I can return my view with my model like this:

```
 public ActionResult Finish()
 {
     //do stuff

     var model = new ModelObject();

     //add stuff to model         

     return View("Execute", model);
 }
```

However, I'm having trouble adding stuff to my url. I need to return the view with this parameter to the end of my url (it basically helps me navigate to a tab on my page):

```
'?tab=tab-survey'
```

Is there a way I can do this? I tried using Redirect and RedirectToAction without any luck:

```
//I get an error when I add this
return RedirectToAction("/Task/ControllerName/Execute/" + id + "?tab=tab-survey", model);
```

Comment: +1 with @Andrew Counts'  answer.  Where are you saving the tab 'state'?  Isn't this (or why isn't it) part of your model?

Comment: I don't want it to be apart of my model since my javascript functions all use the url parameter to do something specific. thanks

Comment: decorate Validate(false) attribute for your execute action method.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to do what you are wanting is by using the `ViewBag()`.  in your controller, you can reference `ViewBag.Tab = "tab-survey";` then in your view you can use `@ViewBag.Tab` as a value item in your javascript or whatever you need.

You should be able to use the "overflow" features of MVC to build your URL, something like the following:

```
return RedirectToAction( new {controller="ControllerName", 
                              action="Execute", id=id, tab="tab-survey"});
```

any variables that match up with route items will be processed appropriately, and anything that doesn't match a route value is just appended to the end of the url.

Comment: yes, that would work. However, my javascript uses what is available in the url, so I was really looking for a way to still append my value to the url

Comment: what error do you get exactly when you use the method you have now?

Comment: I get this: "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?)."

Comment: answer updated with an alternative option

Comment: so where do you pass the model here

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using AJAX, you can do this in your success callback :

```
$.get("/Controller/Action", function(data) {
    //do something with data
    window.location.href = "/Task/Controller/Execut?tab=tab-survey"

    });
```